# Should Staging CLEAN schema of staging stage in data warehousing be the same as Data warehouse schema?

Tags: sql-server, database, etl, data-warehouse

Should Staging CLEAN schema of staging stage in data warehousing  be the same as Data warehouse schema?
Why is staging typically used in banking domain?

Comment: staging stage are the place where you do clean and enrich the data it last stage  schema should be as close as your warehous ...

Comment: Should Staging CLEAN schema of staging stage in data warehousing be the same as Data warehouse schema? No. Why is staging typically used in banking domain? The same reason it is used in any other domain. To pre-clean, process, assign surrogate keys, before loading into the data warehouse.